# ACF and Gutenberg block, how to use blocks without <InnerBlocks />?

Tags: block-editor

I'm working with Gutenberg blocks via ACF. It's great compromise between classic / ACF and the Gutenberg. Another great thing is `<InnerBlocks />`. However, in one block can be used only one `<InnerBlocks />` tag, so it's kind of problematic, if I want to have more control over the html structure in my block. So: I have block with two divs (two columns). In each one I want to use Gutenberg blocks. Is there any way to insert specified block directly in my code, like `image` or `group`, without inner block?

Answer (score 1):

No, [you can't have multiple InnerBlocks](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/25239#issuecomment-692568966). But you can create a second intermediate block, just like WordPress Core does with the [`columns`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/columns) and [`column`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/column) block.

Comment: Thanks! But can I create a second intermediate block directly inside ACF block?